# what is bcount in network tuple received

Tags: tcp, ffprobe, netflow

I am trying to analyse network traffic received from fprobe. Sample tuples Im receiving are like this-

> {
>       "bcount": 52,
>       "protocol": 6,
>       "Timestamp": "2017-11-15 12:07:20.049+0530",
>       "etime": 1048514968,
>       "daddr": "172.24.24.60",
>       "tag": "netflow_data",
>       "pcount": 1,
>       "saddr": "172.24.24.62",
>       "dport": 53345,
>       "sport": 8775,
>       "stime": 1048514968
>   }

I am able to figure out meaning for rest of the fileds except `bcount`. I googled it but not able to get proper answer. What I got after searching is that bcount may be stands for block count or byte count. Does anyone knows what exactly it is and what its significance?

Answer (score 0):

Regular Netflow v5 records usually contains counters for bytes and packets contained within a flow ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetFlow#NetFlow_Record)). You didn't mention which flow collector software you're using (only fprobe for generation), so I can't verify this, but I'm pretty sure `bcount` in your example specifies that there were 52 bytes in the flow record.

This, together with the `pcount` (number of packets in the flow), is significant for identifying the amount of data transferred between the communicating hosts.